# How do I remove the http header in the string returned by HttpResponse in django?

Tags: django, web-services, view, httpresponse, restful-url

I am trying to build a web service system between 2 back-end written in django. However, even after changing the HttpResponse to json type:

`HttpResponse('{"operation":"done"}',mimetype='application/json'`)

I still get the http header information in the other django machine:

```
{u'body': u'{"myjson":"here"}', u'headers': {'status': 200, 'content-length': '235', 'server': 'Google Frontend', 'cache-control': 'private, x-gzip-ok=""', 'date': 'Thu, 05 May 2011 06:16:16 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}}
```

The header information is simply not necessary for me. Is there any convenient way to strip it?

[Edited]
The lib I use to conduct restFUL request is: http://code.google.com/p/python-rest-client/wiki/Using_Connection

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that returned response is a collection type:

```
def getSOAResponse(soa, uri, parameters):
    conn = Connection(soa)
    value = conn.request_get(uri, args=parameters)
    return value
```

If you take the response with the function above, the value you get here is actually a map.

Then you are able to access the body part of the response simply with:

```
body = value['body']
```

Problem solved. The header part of the response is no longer an issue.

[Edited]
Silly me. It's just specified in the doc:
http://code.google.com/p/python-rest-client/wiki/Using_Connection

Comment: -1 because the issue is clearly down to some external libraries (SOAP?) that you didn't mention in either the question or the answer.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I use restFUL request(http://code.google.com/p/python-rest-client/wiki/Using_Connection) to trigger some biz logic in another django and the httpresponse I got back is indeed a collection. I did not see it specified in the doc. But I did not ignore it intentionally. I am a newbie to SOA. That's why I assumed restFUL just work like this.